# Conditional where in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

I have question how can I cleverly handle a conditional where issue.
I have n field filters, e.g.: age, name, sex etc.

And now I can handle this using a dynamic scope:

```
public function scopeAge($query, $age)
{
    if ($age) {
        return $query->where('age', $age);
    }
    return $query;
}
```

and for the other fields so on.

But I need more generic example (write for all fields are a little bit cumbersome). It's possible to figure something using Laravel? I think about class e.g.: `UserQuery`.

```
class UserQuery
{
    private $query;

    public function __construct($query)
    {
        $this->query = $query;
        $this->build();
    }

    private function build()
    {
        $this->appendAge();
        $this->appendName();
    }

    private function appendAge()
    {
        $age = Input::get('age');
        if ($age) {
            $this->query->where('age', $age);
        }
    }

    private function appendName()
    {
        $name = Input::get('name');
        if ($name) {
            $this->query->where('name', $name);
        }
    }

    public function toQuery()
    {
        return $this->query;
    }
}
```

And in model could be called:

```
public function scopeFilters($query)
{
    $userQuery = new UserQuery($query)
    return $userQuery->toQuery();
}
```

This is only my idea, maybe someone has better.

Comment: You familiar with Laracasts? He's done videos on this very topic.

Comment: Maybe you can drop link to this laracast?

Comment: [here's the link that the previous person was talking about](https://laracasts.com/series/eloquent-techniques/episodes/4). Also, there's a [github that has the dedicated filter package](https://github.com/laracasts/Dedicated-Query-String-Filtering/tree/master/app).

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thank you! I was trying to locate it and failing. =)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at this.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/jedrzej/searchable that extends Eloquent models with possibility to filter using query parameters